# How to rotate plot or legend matplotlib (geopandas)

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I have such a problem: i have rotated matplotlib subplot (see the picture):

[image: rotated picture]

it was made by geopandas.plot(). And i have a problem i need to add a legend on this plot, but i need to rotate legend to do it, or to rotate plot.

[image: pic with legend]

To getting plot i use file from this link [shapefile](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/76989a0e57a58ff79c8331af484e779e20200716090804/1ce39b)

I use this code:

```py
russia = geopandas.read_file('admin_level_4.shx', encoding='cp1251')
russia.to_crs(epsg = 23032, inplace = True)
russia.plot.set_axis_off()
```

I use epsg = 23032 due to the fact that by default russia devided into 2 regions (see the picture)

[image: initial plot]

So the question is how to rotate matplotlib plot on 90 degrees or rotate legend?
Or which epsg i should use to have not rotated not divided plot initially